# patsy dmatrices() and statsmodels Logit() - the reference group and the intercept?

Tags: regression, logistic, python, statsmodels

I want to understand what's going on with a categorical variable reference group generated using `dmatrices()`, when building logistic regression models with `sm.Logit()`.

In my toy model I'm predicting the type of transmission (`am`) from fuel consumption (`mpg`) and the engine type (`vs`) using the `mtcars`  data set. `am` and `vs` are categorical variables (0 or 1), and `mpg` is a continuous variable.

When using dmatrices() and not removing the intercept from `dmatrices()`, I get the following output for the model (model1):

[image]

When using dmatrices() and removing the intercept from `dmatrices()`, I get the following output for the model (model2):

[image]

****The problem is** that I don't understand why `C(vs)[0]` is in model2.** I thought it was the reference group and therefore should have been dropped like in model1?

Thanks for any help!

```
# libraries
import pandas as pd 
from patsy import dmatrices
import statsmodels.api as sm

# dataset 
mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars", "datasets", cache=True).data
df = pd.DataFrame(mtcars)

# model 1 (with intercept)
Y1, x1 = dmatrices('am ~ mpg + C(vs)', df, return_type = 'dataframe') 
mod1 = sm.Logit(Y1, x1).fit()
mod1.summary()

# model 2 (without intercept)
Y2, x2 = dmatrices('am ~ 0 + mpg + C(vs)', df, return_type = 'dataframe') 
mod2 = sm.Logit(Y2, x2).fit()
mod2.summary()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put "0 + " in the formula, the explicit intercept (column of 1's) is omitted, but in its place you have indicator variables for all levels of the factor variable (vs), i.e. there is no reference level.  The premise is that you always want an intercept, the only issue is how you want the intercept coded.